# Problems not showing up for c code in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I was doing a little bit of work on my c file when I accidentally turned off the setting which underlines problems. I'm a C novice so this tab is extremely helpful for me to figure out what I did wrong.

My question is what setting turns on error squigglies for C code. An important thing to note is that every other language I program in, the problems show up. So I'm 100% certain that it's language specific.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update! For anyone who is dealing with this hassle here are the four steps I followed. First do what @P.W suggested with the error squigglies.

Secondly, uninstall VSCode.

Next, go to %appdata% and delete the Code folder

Finally, reinstall VSCode.

Hopefully, those steps will solve this problem for anyone who has been looking.

Answer (score 4):

In the workspace settings `json` file, you can add the following line.

```
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
```

That will show the squiggles for both C and C++ files.

This [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) is an useful overview on changing the settings. You will find the language specific editor settings there as well.

Comment: Concise answer and a link to more. That's a good answer. For small C projects, I find it easier to simply use the "Developer Command Prompt" and simply compile directly from the command line. From the command line you can build 5 small projects in the time it takes to navigate the menus just to find the wanted settings in the IDE `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I do the same. I mainly use the IDE for writing code and debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried your idea and it unfortunately failed. The issue is not the squigglies, it's that it does not detect the problem. For example, if I don't use a function, it will spit back an error in the problems tab. However, it still does not do that even with error squigglies enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common problem and the answer is very simple:

step 1 : Go to your working folder through file explorer.

step 2 : Find the folder **.vscode** and open it.

step 3 : Find **settings.json** and open it.

step 4 : look for **"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles":"Disabled",**

step 5 : Replace the text **Disabled** with **Enabled** and save the file.

Comment: Thank me later.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Even though your answer might be right, it is the same as the other answers that have been added over two years ago

Answer (score 0):

In your working folder, you can also see a `.vscode` folder. Find `settings.json` and open it. Find the following line:

```
C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled",
```

Replace the text `Disabled` with `Enabled`, and turn your Problem Checker On.